# Problem using Photos on fresh install

Tags: photos, odin

I have just finished a fresh install of Odin. Started copying my images to the Pictures directory. When they import into the Photos app it seems to create an event for every picture. As you can see in the screenshot, if there are 16 pictures on a single day it'll create 16 events named for that day and each event has 1 photo in it.

I like the fact that it creates date based events from the metadata in the pictures but this doesn't seem usable. There are previous and next buttons but they cannot be used as there is only the single picture in each grouping.

Does anyone know why it would group them this way and how I could fix it?

I'd prefer to actually group them by month automatically instead if possible but even by day would be an improvement.

[image: Photos issue]

Answer (score 0):

I agree this is a little weird import behavior. But you can select all of those images and then right click, and then you can select "Merge Event". This will group all of the photos into a single event.